# Tensorflow - Loss stagnant from first epoch for the same model which showed better results in earlier runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I was training a model for my project on Optical Communication on Colab and this weird thing happened. The model that I trained first, showed near to 99% training and 97% validation accuracy, but the runtime expired sometime in the night. Now, for the same model, I tried re-training after reconnecting to the runtime. But now, the accuracy remains constant from the first epoch at 25%. Surprisingly, there are 4 categories and my model is classifying them all with 0.25. I am not sure what's causing this error because after a few restarts, the model showed similar to original performance but now it's back to the 25% accuracy. Please refer the image and below for the model specs.

[Model Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbwlJ.png)

```
model_fm = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(256,kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(128,kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64,kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = 'softmax')
        ])
model_fm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model_fm.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=256, verbose=1, epochs=60,validation_data=(x_val, y_val), callbacks = [earlystopping, reduce_lr])
```

Earlier progress

```
Epoch 1/60
612/612 [==============================] - 170s 275ms/step - loss: 0.9359 - accuracy: 0.5621 - val_loss: 0.7793 - val_accuracy: 0.6299

Epoch 2/60
612/612 [==============================] - 168s 274ms/step - loss: 0.5998 - accuracy: 0.7369 - val_loss: 0.4597 - val_accuracy: 0.8002

Epoch 3/60
612/612 [==============================] - 173s 284ms/step - loss: 0.4464 - accuracy: 0.8078 - val_loss: 0.3138 - val_accuracy: 0.8693

Epoch 4/60
612/612 [==============================] - 174s 284ms/step - loss: 0.3427 - accuracy: 0.8578 - val_loss: 0.2393 - val_accuracy: 0.9037
```

After restarting runtime:

```
Epoch 1/60
409/409 [==============================] - 112s 273ms/step - loss: 1.3865 - accuracy: 0.2493 - val_loss: 1.3862 - val_accuracy: 0.2594

Epoch 2/60
409/409 [==============================] - 111s 271ms/step - loss: 1.3863 - accuracy: 0.2501 - val_loss: 1.3864 - val_accuracy: 0.2435
```

P.S. Ignore the change in number of samples used for training for the latter case. The model showed similar results for the entire dataset (25% accuracy). I thought maybe using a smaller number of samples might ease the situation, but it didn't.

EDIT 1: The problem recurred again, this time a model showed 99% testing accuracy but when I loaded the same model in a separate notebook to plot some graphs, the accuracy dropped to 33% and guess what, the number of classes was 3.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that it because the first dense layer is very big (16M parameters that represents 99% of the total number of parameters) and therefore your model is really sensitive to initialization and sometimes hard to train.

Answer (score 0):

You have used multiple dense layer in your architecture, when you flatten the final layer, an array of 68k values is created and each value is then   passed as an input to 256 neurons in dense layers. What you can do instead is use GAP layers in between and then flatten and then ust one dense layer ( 4 neurons) or 2 dense layers ( 1st dense layer with 8 neurons ans 2nd with 4 neurons)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But you see, my problem is that the same architecture was working before and now it is not working where I haven't changed anything other than restarting the runtime. If you can help me out on why there is such behavior shown by the model, I'd be very much grateful

Comment: This usually happens with all the models when you try to retrain. Even I am not sure about this behaviour, but according to me what happens is every time when a program is executed it selects a different set of batch of images. To solve this issue you can set random seed. I hope this helps.